# Can a player unretire when the postseason starts who hasn’t played all season and be eligible play in the postseason

Tags: rules, american-football, nfl, postseason

Eric Weddle unretired and is signing with the Rams for their postseason run??? I never heard or seen that in my life is it against any rules?

Comment: You can be 100% sure that the NFL would have nixed this at high speed if it were against the rules; the league office approves all contracts.

Answer (score 4):

When a player retires while under contract, a team can add them to the [*Reserve/Retired List*](https://russellstreetreport.com/salarycap/nfl-glossary/), in which case the contract progression pauses, and would resume if the player unretires.

Also, a player who retires before training camp begins cannot play for another team that season.

It appears Weddle signed a two-year contract with the Rams in 2019, and then retired after one year. It's unclear if the Rams did add him to the Reserve/Retired list in order to hold his rights, but reports of his unretirement say he signed a one-year contract with the Rams, which seems to be a new contract.